# Sscanf forgets to forget the comma in expression

Tags: format, scanf

I am using scanf, trying to read in an expression before a comma.

```
sscanf(some_string,
      "%s %[ .0-9a-zA-Z!@:/|-_^,],read_other_stuff:%s....]", 
      &string1, &string2... etc);
```

Sscanf correct reads in everything up until %[ .0-9a-zA-Z!@:/|-_^,]. This piece of format eats all of the rest of the string, without stopping at a comma, as expected.

How would one make it end at a comma, and read it everything else (including spaces, punctuation other than comma, etc.)

Comment: Take the `,` out of `"%[ .0-9a-zA-Z!@:/|-_^,]"` would be step one.  Maybe use `"%*[^,],"` instead?  Posting some examples would help.  Even `"%*[^,]"` fails unless it scanned at least one non-comma.

Comment: can `string1` contain a `','`?

Comment: Ah... so... ^, does not disinclude the comma. It just says "^" and "," are allowed? I think that might fix it if this is the case.. will try in a moment. (Thank you)

Comment: The idea is that I want the parser to read in everything up until a comma... However, the stuff before the comma has an undetermined number of spaces, which is what prevents me from using %[^,],

Comment: `'^'` is the scan-set negation if it is first.

Answer (score 0):

1. To parse a string up to a `,`, code could use `strchr(some_string, ',')`
2. To use `sscanf()`, use 2 calls

   ```
   int n = 0;
   sscanf(some_string, "%*[^,]%n", &n);
   // some_string[n] is either \0 or ,

   char string1[100];
   string1[0] = '\0';
   sscanf(&some_string[n], ",%99s", string1);

   puts(string1);
   ```

Recommend #1